# Microsoft Graph - Unable to fetch Microsoft exchange room capacity

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-exchange

As stated above I am currently unable to fetch the room capacity per room in `Microsoft Exchange`.

Below is part of my code that `displays the room id, displayName, start time and end time`. But no matter where I search the `room capacity` property is nowhere to see.

```
    const data = calendarEvent.map((event: microsoftgraph.Event) => {
        return {
            id: event.id,
            title: event.location.displayName,
            capacity: event.location.roomCapacity, //(I know this isn't a real graph property) But in theory this is what I am trying to, but I am unable to find a property that has the name capacity. 
            allDay: false,
            start: new Date(event.start.dateTime + "z"), 
            end: new Date(event.end.dateTime + "z"),
        }
    });
```

I've tried looking in ms graph explorer, `/v1.0/me/events` still no property called capacity.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Location doesn't have any property with information about capacity. Why do you suppose that capacity property should exist? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/location?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Comment: The example above was just to give some context and to show what I am trying to do. I know that the location property does not have a capacity property. What I am trying to find out is how to fetch the capacity information. I've tried several properties but none of them seems to have the property, capacity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `displayName` property of the location and make another call to this endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$filter=displayName eq '{name}'
```

Which returns the collection of rooms.

[Room](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/room?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource type has property `capacity` which specifies the capacity of the room.

Resources:

[List places](https://List%20places)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it helped me in the right direction on where to find the capacity of my MS Exchange rooms. I am able to fetch the room data by using pnp/graph graphfi factory interface and use graph.me or graph.users to get the properties. I am however facing a problem on fetching graph.places as it does not show up as a property of the graph object. Could you clarify what you mean by using the `displayName`property of the location and make another call to the endpoint.

Comment: @liondepierre what library do you use for calling Graph API?

Comment: I use PnPJs and use the @pnp/graph graphfi factory interface in SPFx. I don't know if it is any help but for context I access my event properties with the following method `const getSpecificCalendar = async () => {
        await graph.me.events().then((e) => setCalendarEvent(e));
    } `

Comment: @liondepierre Cannot find any method in @pnp/graph to get room data.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Seems like I need to find an alternative for getting `event data` and `places/microsoft.graph.room data`.